# Why doesn't my Eclipse search the $PATH?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to configure my Eclipse 3.8 to compile, flash and debug an ARM SAM7. However, neither the makefile, nor the Run, Debug, External commands menus accept commands. That is, is I say 'gcc', Exlipse complains "Command not found", while, obviously, the shell finds it:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

My system:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.8.0-27-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013
```

If I specify absolute paths at Eclipse, it finds it's targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try absolute path and see what happens

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

or you can define a PATH in eclipse:

**Go to Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Environment -> Add.. -> "${PATH}:/path/to/bin**

Comment: I mentioned this in the last sentence in my question. It works - both for makefiles and external tools.

Comment: It is quite inconvenient to use absolute paths. Mainly because the paths on my colleagues machines might be different.

Comment: @Vorac I think this is the price you should pay when using IDEs. Lots of system programmers use editor+shell because of this problems.

Comment: Your addition to the post looks correct, but now I have `Error creating session
Cannot run program "arm-none-eabi-gdb": Unknown reason`. No idea what is happening.

Comment: @Vorac check your gdb. whereis it and make sure it is installed and do what you did with gcc with it.